# Rails 4: Best schema for a User-Interests relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, schema, relationship

I am new to rails and trying to get the most out of the relationships that can be specified between models. This is not really a coding question but more a design question. I am looking for some guidance on a specific issue regarding the best way to set up model relationships in my Rails app.

Its a straightforward (and common) issue:

I have a model User
I also have a model Interest
Users will have many interests and interests will have many users,
therefore I created a model UserInterest to capture this relationship with simply the user_id and interest_id as columns in the table.

My first question is this: Is this the best approach. Alternatively I could have a column interests in the User table and put an array of interest_id's in it. However, at some point I would like to search for users based on interests so having a join table seems to be a better approach.

The second question relates to creating and updating the Users interests. If the set up above is used, then every time a user updates his interests in the users_interests table, all the current entries for that user must be deleted and a new set created - this seems cumbersome and must be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_intrests
 has_many :intrests, through: :user_intrests
end

class UserIntrest < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :intrest
end

class Intrest < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_intrests
 has_many :users, through: :user_intrests
end
```

you can also learn from  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Your [`has_many through` approach](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is the best one for your given problem. I just would not use `UserInterest` as a model name. But that is just a taste question.